# Don't reset AsyncTask and use onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my `MainActivity` I have a login `view`. While I check for username and password in `AsyncTask`, I show a `ProgressDialog`.

I asked in another question how to not reseting `AsyncTask`and I achieved it with `AndroidManifest.xml`, but I need to save username and password for not to be removed if I change orientation, but `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods are not being called.

I think the problem must be related to `android:configChanges`in `AndroidManifest`. Can you help me?

**Here is my code:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
//Method called when login Button is pressed
public void entrar(View view) {     
    /* Escondemos el teclado */
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextUsuario.getWindowToken(), 0);
    /* Comprobamos si hay conexión a Internet */
    if(myApplication.isOnline()) {
        LoadingMainTask myWebFetch = new LoadingMainTask(this);
        myWebFetch.execute();
    }
    /* Si no se dispone de conexión a Internet, mostramos un error */
    else {
        myApplication.mostrarMensaje(this, R.string.error_conexion_titulo, 
                    R.string.error_conexion_mensaje);
    }
}

private class LoadingMainTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private volatile boolean running = true;
    private MainActivity activity;
    TuplaUsuario tuplaUsuario = new TuplaUsuario();

    private LoadingMainTask(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /** application context. */
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        this.dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (success) {
            /* Si el login no es correcto, mostramos un error por pantalla */
            if (!tuplaUsuario.getOk()) {
                myApplication.mostrarMensaje(activity, R.string.error_datos_login_titulo, 
                        tuplaUsuario.getMensaje());
            }
            /* Entrar */
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, TabsFacturasActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("throw exception post");
            myApplication.throwException(activity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        while (running) {
            try{    
                String usuario = String.valueOf((editTextUsuario).getText());
                String password = String.valueOf((editTextPassword).getText());

                /* Check login */
                                }
                return true;
             } catch (Exception e){
                return false;
             }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        //...
        android:configChanges="orientation" >
        <activity
            //This next two lines are what I was said to use and that works. Other answers were not useful
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you add orientation in android:configChanges it does not fully restarts the running Activity to help it adjust to such changes. So if you need to save username and password override the following method in your MainActivity

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT || newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        //do whatever you want
    }

    }
```

Comment: How should I save data in view for restoring it after change orientation? Because `onConfigurationChanged`doesn't have `Bundle`. I can do `mTextView.getText()`, for example, but how `setText()`?

Comment: you can you cache directory for saving your data temporarili. here is a good example http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-temporarily-writing-and-reading-files-to-cache-directory/

Comment: I've solved that creating a new `Bundle`, adding data to it and calling `onCreate`with it.

Comment: If you are calling oncreate in case of orientation change then why not you  just remove the orientation from manifest configuration tag.

Comment: I want orientation can be changed. I call `onCreate`but after I've saved `view`data in `Bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

With `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` you are telling your system that you handle a change of orientation on your own. Which results in your activity not being restarted and therefore on `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`not being called in case of an orientation change. Use `onConfigurationChanged` instead.